# Flutter TextField maxLength not enforced

Tags: flutter, textfield, maxlength

I'm implementing two simple dialogs to allow the user to edit two settings in my app. They're very similar, as you can see from the code.
First one, used to input a 5-digit number (I convert the `String` into a number later):

```
var tfController = TextEditingController();
String newPort = await showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Center(
            heightFactor: 1,
            child: TextField(
              controller: tfController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              maxLength: 5,
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Insert number:"), 
              onEditingComplete: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(tfController.text);
              },
            )),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.done),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(tfController.text);
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              })
        ],
      );
    });
```

Second dialog, a generic text input:

```
var tfController = TextEditingController();
String newHeader = await showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Center(
            heightFactor: 1,
            child: TextField(
              controller: tfController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              maxLength: 30,
              maxLengthEnforced: true, //added later even if it's true by default, doesn't change anything
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Insert text:"),
              onEditingComplete: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(tfController.text);
              },
            )),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.done),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(tfController.text);
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              })
        ],
      );
    });
```

The first dialog works perfectly: when needed, it pops up with the field already focused, the keyboard shows only numbers, and the input is limited automatically at length 5, as expected. So, when I needed the user to input a limited text string, I simply duplicated the code, changing just the length.
Everything seemed to work fine, so at first I didn't even bother to check if the `maxLength` was enforced: I only discovered, much later, that the second dialog allows the user to exceed the maximum length, although it correctly changed the color of the hint and the underline to red, to let the user know that something was wrong.

I know I can easily set up a work-around for this, like truncating the String after the user confirms the input, but **the question is more about WHY the two dialogs act differently than how to solve this**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has become irrelevant, since the *maxLengthEnforced* argument has been deprecated and has been replaced with *maxLengthEnforcement*, which has a more complex behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that some time it works or not,i had same problem using `maxLength`and i have solved it by using `inputFormatters` property. The following code would limit the textFormField to 30 in length :

**Import the package first**. `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

```
new TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(30),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I know how to solve this and get only the first 30 characters. My question is about why I don't need an inputFormatter for the first dialog, while it's necessary for the second

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [official document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLength.html) carefully.

> **maxLength property**
>
> The maximum number of characters (Unicode scalar values) to allow in the text field.
>
> If set, a character counter will be displayed below the field showing how many characters have been entered. If set to a number greater than 0, it will also display the maximum number allowed. If set to TextField.noMaxLength then only the current character count is displayed.
>
> After maxLength characters have been input, additional input is ignored, unless maxLengthEnforced is set to false. The text field enforces the length with a LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter, which is evaluated after the supplied inputFormatters, if any.
>
> This value must be either null, TextField.noMaxLength, or greater than 0. If null (the default) then there is no limit to the number of characters that can be entered. If set to TextField.noMaxLength, then no limit will be enforced, but the number of characters entered will still be displayed.
>
> Whitespace characters (e.g. newline, space, tab) are included in the character count.
>
> If maxLengthEnforced is set to false, then more than maxLength characters may be entered, but the error counter and divider will switch to the decoration's InputDecoration.errorStyle when the limit is exceeded.
>
> **Limitations**
> The text field does not currently count Unicode grapheme clusters (i.e. characters visible to the user), it counts Unicode scalar values, which leaves out a number of useful possible characters (like many emoji and composed characters), so this will be inaccurate in the presence of those characters. If you expect to encounter these kinds of characters, be generous in the maxLength used.
>
> For instance, the character "ö" can be represented as '\u{006F}\u{0308}', which is the letter "o" followed by a composed diaeresis "¨", or it can be represented as '\u{00F6}', which is the Unicode scalar value "LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS". In the first case, the text field will count two characters, and the second case will be counted as one character, even though the user can see no difference in the input.
>
> Similarly, some emoji are represented by multiple scalar values. The Unicode "THUMBS UP SIGN + MEDIUM SKIN TONE MODIFIER", "", should be counted as a single character, but because it is a combination of two Unicode scalar values, '\u{1F44D}\u{1F3FD}', it is counted as two characters.

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter-class.html) is what you are looking for. @Assassin has a good answer.

Comment: As I commented above, I don't need a way to truncate the input to 30 characters. I'd like to understand why the first dialog doesn't need an inputFormatter (or any other solution), while the second one does.
Unless there's something I'm still missing in the docs, I see no hint on the reason of this different behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to flutter 1.22.6

Write a command in the console:

```
flutter version 1.22.6
```